# Opera Extension xmlhttp.send(); error

Tags: opera

I am having a problem connecting to a java application using my opera extension
I already did this extension in chrome a it work.

this is the code in javascritp in the popup.html

```
function AtribuirID(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var texto = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var splitagem=texto.split("(user)"); 
            localStorage.setItem('ID',splitagem[0]);
            localStorage.setItem('Auxiliar',splitagem[1]);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:10002?z=AtribuirID",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The problem is that i am getting a error Uncaught exception: DOMException: NETWORK_ERR in xmlhttp.send() and i cant access my application in java that suppose to be the server part.
I have already put the  network="public private" in the config.xml but it didnt work

Comment: Perhaps, the Java applet isn't ready yet (not fully loaded yet) when `AtribuirID` is called.

Comment: the java aplication is ready because I already did this extension in chrome and it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in config.xml file add this line: `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>` to allow any domain httprequest before `</widget>` tab, this solve the problem, if problems persist, open in opera browser tab "opera:config" and select "Users Prefs" and check "Allow File XMLHttpRequest" and restart. if have problem i can send you my opera extension working fine...

Comment: Great. Stylesheets and tilemaps (in cocos2d-html) are loaded correctly now. Thanks!